# VPC Connector error while creating Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Am trying to create a Cloud Function in a GCP environment.

Am getting the error under 'CONNECTIONS' egress settings stating 'VPC connector is required'. In other gcp projects, this egress setting is sett to None and it's working. Any help on what needs to be done?

I am not able to proceed to the next step in the wizard. I tried with various variations i.e. Cloud Storage trigger, pub/sub trigger/ https but the issue persists.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occurred with two conditions mentioned below:

1. If your project has organization policy `Require VPC Connector (Cloud Functions) - constraints/cloudfunctions.requireVPCConnector` inherited. Therefore, the Cloud Function requires a Network field to be specified on the creation. That’s the reason in other GCP projects, when egress setting is set to None and it's working.

   To resolve your issue,you can modify the organization policy value for this project which will allow the Cloud Function to be successfully created without a Network field. Follow this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls#require_vpc_connector) to check and remove the policy.
2. If you are trying to use the Cloud Function to connect to Kubernetes API which is across multiple projects then only the VPC is used where your nodes are located, and any [authorized networks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks) in the VPC will be able to access the control plane. This is due to the control plane for your cluster being [located in a Google-owned project](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#the_control_plane_in_private_clusters), and reachable through VPC peering. Attaching a [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/calling-an-internal-gke-service-from-cloud-functions-2958f9218355) written by Neil Kolban for your additional reference.

Check the above conditions and let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: The first proposition seems the good one!

Comment: Thanks Sai. That seems to be the way to go. I have raised it with the Infra team.